# Jetpack Composables with TCP Socket Connection Crashing

Tags: sockets, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, tcpclient, android-jetpack-compose

I am using Jetpack Composables and Android WiFi P2P API guide to create buttons and animation but trying to maintain an active TCP socket to output and receive data. However, whenever the program tries to establishes the connection using "socket.connect((InetSocketAddress())" it crashes the app.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    val manager: WifiP2pManager? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE) as WifiP2pManager?
    }

    var channel: WifiP2pManager.Channel? = null
    var receiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Obtain an instance of WifiP2pManager and register application with the Wi-Fi P2P framework
        // Initialize() method returns a WifiP2pManager.Channel, which is used to connect application to the Wi-Fi P2P framework
        channel = manager?.initialize(this, mainLooper, null)
        channel?.also { channel ->
            receiver = manager?.let { WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(it, channel) }
        }


        setContent {
                createButtons()
                createAnimatingImages()

                val socket = Socket()
                var buf = ByteArray(1024)


                try {
                    socket.bind(null)
                    socket.connect((InetSocketAddress(host, port)), 500)
                    if (socket.isConnected) {
                        println("Client Connected to " + host + " at " + port)
                    }

                    try {
                        val outputStream: OutputStream = socket.getOutputStream()
                        buf = doSomething(...)
                        outputStream.write(buf)
                        outputStream.flush()

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                println("IO Exception")
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    //catch logic
                }

        }
```

Comment: Click the Logcat tab in Android Studio if you use it, and always share the logs for crash reports.

Comment: You should not call non composable code inside composable function, because it can be recomposed and called again. Move your socket calls to Viewmodel or activity's function

Comment: @VygintasB  I'm not too familiar with ViewModels yet. I have tried to follow online examples, but alot of the github examples crash upon launch when i use the latest Kotlin 1.5 and Android Studio Canary 2. Is there a basic structure i can follow somewhere using the latest and greatest for setting up a TCP socket with viewmodel?